# Binding ckeditor content to model in asp.net 5 without using js

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I try to retrieve data from a ckeditor but failed. My code is as follow

```
@model Test.ViewModel.MyViewModel
<textarea name="my-textarea" asp-for="content" class="form-control form-gap" placeholder="Main Content"></textarea>
        <script type="text/javascript"> CKEDITOR.replace('my-textarea'); </script>
```

I bind the textarea to an element called content in MyViewModel. If I don't use ckeditor, I am able to get the content in textarea in my action. However, if I use ckeditor, I am not able to do so. I saw some articles talking about using javascript, but I would like to use C# itself. Can anyone help to see what is wrong and what I should do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is untested and I've always used the ckeditor with JavaScript, but searching on nuget I found this package https://www.nuget.org/packages/CKeditor.Mvc that I think you can use. In
http://forums.asp.net/t/2012709.aspx?How+to+Implement+a+CKeditor+in+MVC, someone elaborates on how it can be used.

```
//Notice the attribute (AllowHtml)
public class BlogEntry {

    [AllowHtml] 
    public string BlogText {get;set;}
}
```

Add this to your view

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.BlogEntry
```

And, of course, have your input

```
<input type="text" id="BlogText" name="BlogText" />
```